# react-router v4 fails to render a nested route when the path is typed into browser's adress bar

Tags: reactjs, routes, redux, react-router, react-redux

I got a problem with rendering nested routes with react-router v4. Whenever I type bla-bla.com/userId/postId into my browser's adress bar nothing gets rendered, however when I go to bla-bla.com/userId and then click on a link to a post and get redirected to the post's route everything works fine and I see the post's page. When I type '/:userId/:blogId' manually I see contents of my index.html file inside bundle.js, which causes the error. What can I do to make '/:userId/:blogId' route accessible without having to go to '/:userId' first? That's how I render it on the server:

```
 app.use('*',(req,res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'index.html')));
```

Route config:

```
    <Switch>
       <PrivateRoute component={Users} exact={true} path={'/users'}/>
       <PrivateRoute component={BlogPage} exact={true} path={'/:userId/:blogId'}/>
       <PrivateRoute component={UserPage} exact={true} path={'/:userId'}/>
    </Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it didn't work was that I tried to access bundle.js from index.html like `src="./bundle.js"` which caused the client to take it from '/userId/bundle.js' when I typed any nested url manually. When I hardcoded the path to the bundle into index.html like so `http://localhost:8080/bundle.js` it fixed the problem.